# Chamar Jquery Validate no submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma validação de dois campos utilizando o `remote` do *jquery Validate* para evitar duplicidade na base.

Exemplo:

```
Campo A = Teste
Campo B = Minas Gerais
```

Adicionei o `remote` no `campo B` e a validação inicial funciona, porém quando faço a alteração no `campo A` ele não chama a validação novamente.

Consegui resolver o problema utilizando a dica desse link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313417/using-jquery-validate-remote-on-multi-select-element

Com base nele criei minha função no onChange que ficou assim:

```
$("#descricao").change(function () {
     $("#id").removeData("previousValue");
     $(addForm).validate().element("#id");
});
```

Obrigado a todos que responderam!

Comment: Posta o código do que tu fez até agora, assim fica mais fácil de alguém te ajudar.

Comment: Isso ajuda? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941338/validating-multiple-forms-on-the-same-page

Comment: ou isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354322/jquery-remote-validation-for-multiple-fields